# import value javascript to flask

Tags: javascript, html, python, flask

Я новичок в разработке на python и в целях изучения языка решил написать простую статистику сайта. Я создал свой локальный сервер на flask и несколько html страничек. Для показа статистики использую метод request. 
Вывод статистики делаю вот так:

```
    from flask import Flask , request 

def main():
    f = open('users.txt', 'a')
    if request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') is None:
        ip = (request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    else:
        ip = (request.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    f.write('New connect ' + str(datetime.now()) + ' IP address: ' + ip + ' ' + str(headers) + '\n')
    f.close()
```

Мне стало интересно , как получить разрешение экрана пользователя сайта, и я добавил в код html скрипт js который может выводить разрешение экрана.
Выглядит так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Start page</title>
</head>
<body>
example page <br>
<a class="Link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/gallery">Link to gallery</a>
<a class="Link" href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/about">Link to about</a>
</body>
</html>

<script language=JavaScript>
r1=(screen.width+'*'+screen.height+'&nbsp;');
document.write(r1)
</script>
```

То есть при запуске сервера и подключении на эту страницу мне выводит мое разрешение в цифрах. 
Но как мне эту цифру импортировать в файл .py и использовать для записи статистики?

Comment: вам нужно отправить данные на back - используйте forms/post или ajax

Comment: А как это сделать с помощью forms/post ? Не понял

Comment: java script -ом отправляете данные на определённый url, а на back - принимаете по этому url и вовлекаете в скрипт - сохраните в бд или тип того